# ValueError: No 'serving_default' in the SavedModel's SignatureDefs. Possible values are 'name_of_my_model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I am trying to quantize a Tensorflow **SavedModel** using the following command line:

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=/tmp/foo.tflite \
  --saved_model_dir=/tmp/saved_model
```

But I get the following Error:

```
ValueError: No 'serving_default' in the SavedModel's SignatureDefs. Possible values are 'my model name'
```

I already checked, a **signature_def_map** was defined when exporting the model.

The command:

```
saved_model_cli show --dir /tmp/mobilenet/1 --tag_set serve
```

returns

```
The given SavedModel MetaGraphDef contains SignatureDefs with the following keys:
SignatureDef key: 'name_of_my_model'
```

and:

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['is_training'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_BOOL
      shape: ()
      name: is_training:0
  inputs['question1_embedding'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 35, 300)
      name: question1_embedding:0
  inputs['question2_embedding'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 35, 300)
      name: question2_embedding:0
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
  outputs['prediction'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, 1)
      name: prediction:0
Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Comment: Is your `saved_model` dir containts the `assets` and `variables` folder with `.pb` graph?

Comment: **variables** yes, I have no **assets**

Comment: Try this command `saved_model_cli show --dir /tmp/mobilenet/1 --tag_set serve` in command line. For more [information](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/saved_model). I thinks there is problem in creating `saved_model`. Because usually when you execute `!ls /tmp/saved_model`,  folder contatins `assets  saved_model.pb  variables`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `saved_model_signature_key` to specify the signature name when converting

```
tflite_convert \
         --output_file=/tmp/foo.tflite \
         --saved_model_dir=/tmp/saved_model \
         --saved_model_signature_key='my model name'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but explain what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question.